# how test if char array is null?

Tags: arrays, null, char

I've been doing (in C)

```
char array[100];
if (array == NULL)
   something;
```

which is very wrong (which I have finally learned since my program doesn't work).  What is the equivalent where I could test a new array to see if nothing has been put in it yet?

Also, how do you make an array empty/clean it out?

I know there are other posts out on this topic out there, but I couldn't find a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array declared with

```
char array[100]
```

always has 100 characters in it.

By "cleaning out" you may mean assigning a particular character to each slot, such as the character `'\0'`.  You can do this with a loop, or one of several library calls to clear memory or move memory blocks.

Look at [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) -- it can "clear" or "reset" your array nicely.

If you are working with strings, with are special char arrays terminated with a zero, then in order to **test** for an empty array, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793867/best-way-to-check-if-a-character-array-is-empty).  Otherwise if you have a regular character array not intended to represent text, write a loop to make sure all entries in the array are your special blank character, whatever you choose it to be.

You can also declare your character array like so:

```
char* array = malloc(100);
```

or even

```
char* array = NULL;
```

but that is a little different.  In this case the array being NULL means "no array has been allocated" which is different from "an array has been allocated but I have not put anything in it yet."